# TextInputLayout box color

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

Using the following xml element I can properly color the TextInputLayout box white but that's only after clicking it. The initial color is still default.

```
     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
            android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:maxLines="1" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Is there a way to color the box and hint text in a way that not only applies after actually giving the TextInput focus?

Comment: you can change `"colorControlActivated"` from your app theme which is used to highlight border of TextInput.

Answer (score 1):

To change the color in the `TextInputLayout` just use something like:

```
  <style name="OutlinedBoxColor" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <!-- border color in OutlinedBox
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_layout_stroke_color</item>

    <!-- The color of the label when it is collapsed and the text field is active -->
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/singleColor</item>
    <!-- The color of the label in all other text field states (such as resting and disabled) -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/.....</item>
  </style>
```

The result when the `TextInputLayout` is focused and not focused
[image] [image]

You should use a color selector for these colors:

For `boxStrokeColor`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.87" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

For the `android:textColorHint`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.6" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

create `Selector` inside res/color/text_input_box_stroke.xml put something like the following:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#fcc" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:color="#cfc" android:state_hovered="true"/>
    <item android:color="#ccf"/>
</selector>
```

Then in your `styles.xml` put:

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_box_stroke</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">2dp</item>
</style>
```

Finally, use that style in your `TextInputLayout`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight">
    ........
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Add  `text_input_box_color` in your `color.xml`

```
<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color" tools:override="true">#fff</color>
```

for more detail check [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md#outline-box)