# How to remove bottom highlight in AppCompatEditText Inside TextInputLayout on Material Theme?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I'm creating a password field with custom background using `TextInputLayout` and `AppCompatEditText`. Before using `Theme.MaterialComponents` the the field was fine, but after using it, my `AppCompatEditText` start showing a line highlight at the bottom. I'm sure it is because of Material styling, but I couldn't figure out which attribute I can use to remove the line and I also not really sure whether it is on the `TextInputLayout` or the `AppCompatEditText`.

[image: EditText with bottom highlight]

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_input_border"
                android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
                android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="13dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: You should use the `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText` instead of `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText`. Currently **you can't  hide** the underline, you can only change the color of the **stroke**. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57985955/2016562). However you can use the **`Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox` style** in the `TextInputLayout` and **remove** the `android:background="@drawable/bg_input_border"`.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I've used `OutlinedBox` style and it's great, but the focused `EditText` still have the stroke. Is it also unhideable?

Comment: Also in this case you can use the boxStrokeColor. It is a selector, and you can use the same color when it is focused. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56292017/textinputlayout-box-color/57884207#57884207)

Answer (score 0):

You can set boxStrokeWidth value

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
    ...
```

or Programmatically

```
textInputLayout.setBoxStrokeWidth(0);
```